# Removing CNAME on Github

Tags: url, github, cname

How do I stop my Github webpage from redirecting to an expired CNAME URL? I know it takes time, but my Github page has not stopped redirecting even after 1.5 days! I am asking to find out if there's any step I missed (all I did was delete the CNAME file). If there's no step I'm missing, how long does it usually take to stop redirecting? I really need my page to be available soon since it is recruiting season. Please help!

Comment: "All I did was delete the CNAME file." You pushed that change to GitHub? That should be enough. Try [contacting their support team](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: Update: Fixed the problem by deleting the CNAME file which actually worked correctly, but I forgot to clear my browser cache and wasn't able to see the change

Comment: 4 yrs later I face the same issue and clearing the cache works. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the custom domain field. Let it remain empty. Then click the save button. Then clear cache of your browser or open in another browser / incognito mode. You will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your browser cache. Because your browser has saved memory to redirect to the cname site every time you open the github page link.

Another solution is that you can open the github page link with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by following 2 steps,

1. Delete the CNAME file from git folder (git rm CNAME), and have your git updated.
2. From your domain provider, remove any DNS settings (Custom CNAME) that you have for the specified domain.

These are the steps, I followed to get it working correctly.